# Proxy for only one browser with CefSharp Offscreen

Tags: c#, proxy, cefsharp

I am trying to set a proxy for a `ChromiumWebBrowser()` without changing the settings of other browsers.

My code looks like this :

**CEF initialization**

Here I will initialize CefSharp and call the method that will test to set the proxy

```
public CFTryOut()
    {
        var settings = new CefSettings()
        {
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache"),
        };

        CefSharpSettings.ShutdownOnExit = true;

        Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

        ProxyTest();

    }
```

**ProxyTest**

Here I want to create two `ChromiumWebBrowser()` and set a proxy to only one of them

```
async Task ProxyTest()
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser firstbrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        ChromiumWebBrowser secondbrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

        waitini:
        if (!firstbrowser.IsBrowserInitialized && !secondbrowser.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            goto waitini;
        }

        firstbrowser.LoadingStateChanged += FirstBrowserLoadingStateChanged;
        secondbrowser.LoadingStateChanged += SecondBrowserLoadingStateChanged;

        OpenSync("http://icanhazip.com/", firstbrowser);
        string x = await firstbrowser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();

        //Set the Proxy
        await Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
        {
            var rc = firstbrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;
            var v = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            v["mode"] = "fixed_servers";
            v["server"] = "http://45.77.248.104:8888";
            string error;
            bool success = rc.SetPreference("proxy", v, out error);
        });

        OpenSync("http://icanhazip.com/", firstbrowser);
        string y = await firstbrowser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();

        OpenSync("http://icanhazip.com/", secondbrowser);
        string z = await secondbrowser.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync();


    }
```

Here, the `First/SecondBrowserLoadingStateChanged`allow me to flag when the page loading is finished in order for `OpenSync` to wait for page loading to end before returning :

```
public void OpenSync(string url, ChromiumWebBrowser browser)
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        browser.Load(url);
        SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => !IsLoading);
    }
```

**What I expect**

x = my ip - xx.xx.xx.xx

y = proxy's ip - 45.77.248.104

z = my ip - xx.xx.xx.xx

**What I got**

x = my ip - xx.xx.xx.xx

y = proxy's ip - 45.77.248.104

z = proxy's ip - 45.77.248.104

The thing is I did not set any proxy on the `secondbrowser` yet the request goes through the proxy. I guess that's because they share the same host.

So

**1) how can I specify a dedicated proxy for each `ChromiumWebBrowser` ?**

or

**2) how can I specify a different host for each new `ChromiumWebBrowser` ?**

Comment: Pass in a new RequestContext to the browser constructor. At the moment they share the one global context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @amaitland it was pretty easy actually.

My problem was that I was trying to set the RequestContext after the browser initialization, while it's read only.

But it can be passed as a parameter in the constructor :

```
        var rc1 = new RequestContext();
        ChromiumWebBrowser firstbrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("", null, rc1);
        var rc2 = new RequestContext();
        ChromiumWebBrowser secondbrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("", null, rc2);
```

All credit to Amaitland

For a more reusable way, the process to set the proxy can be deported like this :

```
    async private Task SetProxy(ChromiumWebBrowser cwb, string Address)
    {
        await Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
        {
            var rc = cwb.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;
            var v = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            v["mode"] = "fixed_servers";
            v["server"] = Address;
            string error;
            bool success = rc.SetPreference("proxy", v, out error);
        });
    }
```

Then I can call :

```
SetProxy(firstbrowser, "123.123.123.123:1234")
```

Comment: Are you setting the proxy using the dot notation method or with a dictionary as per your question? If you're are able to share the relevant code that would be most useful!

Comment: @inthegarden if by dot notation you mean `"123.123.123.123:1234"` then yes, I declare it like this. Note that in the code from my first post I declared it with `http://` but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

/Perfectionism Mode On

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CefSharp;

namespace Extensions
{
    public static class WebBrowserExtensions
    {
        public static Task SetProxy(this IWebBrowser webBrowser, string address)
        {
            return Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var context = webBrowser.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;

                context.SetPreference("proxy", new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["mode"] = "fixed_servers",
                    ["server"] = address
                }, out _);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
await browser.SetProxy("111.111.111.111:1111")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right, but when using ("asyn") remember

```
   async private Task SetProxy(ChromiumWebBrowser cwb, string Address)
    {
        await Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
        {
            var rc = cwb.GetBrowser().GetHost().RequestContext;
            var v = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            v["mode"] = "fixed_servers";
            v["server"] = Address;
            string error;
            bool success = rc.SetPreference("proxy", v, out error);
        });
    }
```

Sample use:

```
   public async void dd1()
    {
      await SetProxy(firstbrowser, "123.123.123.123:1234")  
    }
```