# Cef can only be initialized once. Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

I am trying to code an application that will launch several different browser, each with a different proxy, so I use `Cef.Initialize` to give a different proxy to each of my browser, but here I get this error and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

> "Cef can only be initialized once. Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception."

```
private void Start()
{

  CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

  settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("proxy-server", Proxy);
  Cef.Initialize(settings);
}
```

Comment: As the exception says you can only initialize once. Read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#proxy-resolution don't set the proxy via command line when using a `RequestContext`.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613266/proxy-for-only-one-browser-with-cefsharp-offscreen?rq=1